# Java SSL SOAP Client using PEM file

Tags: java, ssl, soap, pfx

I would like to use a PEM file to set up a SSL Soap Connection.
I don't want to use the java keystore command line as I need this application to be portable.

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way we are doing this is by using BouncyCastle [PEMReader](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonah/bc/org/bouncycastle/openssl/PEMReader.html)

Sample Code for Private Key

```
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream( filename ), "US-ASCII" );
        PEMReader pemReader = new PEMReader( reader );
        PrivateKey privateKey = ( PrivateKey ) pemReader.readObject();
        pemReader.close();
```

For X509 Certificates

```
        X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) pemReader.readObject();
```

Then initialize the KeyStore

```
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance( "JKS" );
        ks.load( null, KSPASSWORD );
        ks.setKeyEntry( "Client: " + subject, privateKey, KSPASSWORD, [certificate] );
```